# Arrayfire array from complex host data

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, arrayfire

I'm having a problem initializing an arrayfire array from host data.

The following code will not link for me:

```
constexp int mNumEigenInfos = 100;
std::complex<float> mEigenVectors[mNumEigenInfos][6];
af::array mEigenVectorsArray = af::array((dim_t)6,(dim_t)(mNumEigenInfos),reinterpret_cast<float2*>(mEigenVectors));
```

Giving me an error of:

```
undefined reference to `af::array::array<float2>(long long, long long, float2 const*, af_source)'
```

Now if i change the reinterpret_cast from float2* to float*:

```
constexp int mNumEigenInfos = 100;
std::complex<float> mEigenVectors[mNumEigenInfos][6];
af::array mEigenVectorsArray = af::array((dim_t)6,(dim_t)(mNumEigenInfos),reinterpret_cast<float*>(mEigenVectors));
```

It links fine. From reading online, i thought i was supposed to treat complex data as a cuComplex (which casting to float2 or cuComplex gives the exact same error since they are the same thing).

I feel like i'm making a stupid mistake here but can't seem to figure it out.

How am i supposed to initialize an arrayfire array from std::complex host data?

Thank you for your Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kind of similar to the question [af::array::device doesn't work with complex arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392739/afarraydevice-doesnt-work-with-complex-arrays) please have a look - the only difference is the direction in which complex data is passed.

The following should work fine as `std::complex` should be ABI compatible with `af::cfloat`.

```cpp
af::array mEigenVectorsArray =
    af::array((dim_t)6, (dim_t)(mNumEigenInfos),
              reinterpret_cast<af::cfloat>(mEigenVectors));
```

ArrayFire API won't have a symbol for function with `float2` type, however it will have the symbol for function with type `af::cfloat`. Even `cuFloatComplext` or `float2` should also be ABI compatible with `af::cfloat` I think. So, reinterpret-cast to `af::cfloat` is what should be done.